# GridSearch CV: Suitable scoring metrics for Imbalanced data sets

Tags: class-imbalance, grid-search

I am new to machine learning.
This is my $1^{st}$ machine learning project and I am working on classification on an imbalanced dataset. There are also multi-classes in the target variable.

I would like to know what is the most suitable metrics for scoring the performance in the GridSearchCV.

I think

1. **roc_au** is sometimes used for imbalanced dataset. But there are several

‘roc_auc’
‘roc_auc_ovo’
‘roc_auc_ovr’
Which should I use?

2. Alternatively, **precision-recall_auc** is also used. But I can't seem to find this scoring metrics for GridSearchCV. How do I use it in GridSearchCV?

Thank you

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_total, Y_total, random_state=0, test_size=0.25)
kfold =GroupKFold(n_splits=3)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0), hyperF, cv = kfold, scoring=, verbose = 1, n_jobs = -1)
```

Comment: Each of those scores can also just be specified as 'weighted', same with f1_score.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use scikit-learn's [average_precision_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) which is very similar to area under the precision-recall curve.

Since average_precision_score is a metric it will will work with scikit-learn's GridSearchCV.

Answer (score 0):

Before performing Train Test Split, The most fundamental step for handling imbalanced data is to do UnderSampling or OverSampling , most of the SMOTE is what is recommended for the imbalaced data. you can use python package imblearn to do the SMOTE.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first of all identifying your major and minor classes, identify which quantity out of **True Positive**, **True Negative**, **False Positive** and **False Negative** would you like to optimize and then choose the corresponding metric.

For the choice of metric I would suggest either going for **Precision**, **Recall** or **F1 score** (major or minor) depending on the quantity selected above.